# React useState change icon from hamburger to close icon fas-fa-times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

This is my code: https://github.com/reouen/bikes/tree/main/src/components

```
<i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}/>
```

^ This above should change icon to fas fa-times together with useState below after clicking on it. Why it doesnt work?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Button from './Button'
import './Navbar.css'
import Dropdown from './Dropdown'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Navbar() {
    const {click, setClick} = useState(false)
    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click)
    
    return (
         <nav className="Navbar">
             <Link to="/" className="Navbar-logo">
             EPIC
             </Link>
             <div className="menu-icon">
             <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}/>

             </div>
             </nav>   
        
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you haven't added onClick event listener to the menu icon div

```
<div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
     <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}/>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
  const handleClick = () => {
    setClick((curr) => !curr)
  }

  return (
    <nav className="Navbar">
      <Link to="/" className="Navbar-logo">
        EPIC
      </Link>
      <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
        <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click)
  return (
    
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="navbar-cantainer">
        <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo">
        EPIC 
        </Link>
        <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
          <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>
   
         
  )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).